# Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile <filename> with wildcard in filename

Tags: windows, powershell

How can I quote wildcards in the -OutFile parameter of Invoke-WebRequest?

```
$filename = "Image[1].jpg"
$uri = [System.Uri]"http:/url/to/image.jpg"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $filename
```

This code gives me an exception:

```
Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path Image[1].jpg did not resolve to a file.
```

[Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730956.aspx) 
says

> Two things to note here. First, we enclosed the path name in single quote marks. That’s not mandatory, but it makes our command a bit easier on the eyes. (As you’ll see in a minute). Second, we needed to preface the square bracket with two back tick characters (``); this tells PowerShell that we want to treat the left square bracket as a regular character and not a wildcard character. Like we said, it looks crazy, but it works:

```
$filename = 'Image``[1``].jpg'
```

Gives me:

```
Cannot perform operation because the wildcard path Image``[1``].jpg did not resolve to a file.
```

Changing the file name to

```
$filename = "Image``[1``].jpg"
```

doesn't generate an exception, but the name of the saved file is

```
Image`[1`].jpg
```

I would love to change the filenames, but it is a requirement that they maintain the same name when they are downloaded.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thx

Comment: Im confused why do you need wild cards on a outfile?

Comment: It's a reported issue https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3174 with no comments. Claims there are workarounds, but doesn't mention any. @ArcSet I don't think the questioner does need wildcards on an outfile...

Comment: @ArcSet I don't need wildcards on an outfile, but Powershell interprets any [,],*,? in a path as a wildcard.  [ and ] are legal characters for windows filenames and I am trying to download a file that contains [ and ] and preserve it's filename.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks for the info I was driving myself nuts trying to escape the square brackets

Answer (score 2):

Not elegante solution:

```
$filename = 'c:\temp\Image(1).jpg'
$uri = [System.Uri]"http://www.google.fr"
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -OutFile $filename
Rename-Item $filename $filename.Replace('(', '[').Replace(')', ']')
```